# How to create a scripted sequence

Tags: c++, sdl

Like countless other video games, I'd like to have scripted sequences in my game. Character 1 says something, the player replies, then a rock falls, that sorta stuff. I *could* find a way to do it, but I would like to use a common method, assuming there is one.

My current thought is to have a separate file for each level of the game that contains all the possible scripted actions for that level. When the corresponding trigger is activated, the function is called. I think early Call of Duty games (up to CoD4) used something similar, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: As it stands, this question is rather broad.  A design for a system like this will depend on many factors, such as its requirements, and the architecture of the engine in which it is being developed.  Try narrowing the scope of the question a bit.